# update defaultdict count according to the occurrence of tuples in two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, counter

I have two lists and would like to create a dictionary to record the occurrence of tuples.

My current code:

```
tup_to_find_test = [('good', 'pea'), ('leaf', 'sweet')] 
self_per_list_test = [('leaf', 'liquid'), ('leaf', 'sweet'), ('leaf', 'sweet'),('good', 'pea'),('good', 'pea'),('good', 'pea')]
from collections import defaultdict
tup_dict_test = defaultdict(int)
for tup_to_find_test in self_per_list_test:
   tup_dict_test[tup_to_find_test]+=1
```

My result is:

```
defaultdict(int, {('leaf', 'liquid'): 1, ('leaf', 'sweet'): 1, ('good', 'pea'): 3})
```

My desired result is:

```
('leaf', 'liquid'): 0, ('leaf', 'sweet'): 2, ('good', 'pea'): 3})
```

I do not know why the count of `('leaf', 'liquid')` is 1. Isn't the default integer of `defaultdict(int)` zero? Why I got 1 for the `('leaf', 'liquid')` tuple?

Comment: You have `('leaf', 'liquid')` in `self_per_list_test` once, so its count is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line isn't doing what you think it is:

```
for tup_to_find_test in self_per_list_test:
   # ...
```

Here you are **iterating a list elementwise**, in this case the elements of `self_per_list_test`. There's *no filtering* taking place. As your `for` loop iterates, `tup_to_find_test` successively represents `('leaf', 'liquid')`, `('leaf', 'sweet')`, etc. The fact the name is the same as a variable you've defined earlier only serves to confuse.

Instead, you can use a ternary statement to differentiate operations:

```
for item in self_per_list_test:
    tup_dict_test[item] += 1 if item in tup_to_find_test else 0

print(tup_dict_test)

defaultdict(int, {('leaf', 'liquid'): 0, ('leaf', 'sweet'): 2, ('good', 'pea'): 3})
```

---

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is more idiomatic with Python. It's good practice to use `set` for O(1) lookup within a dictionary comprehension.

```
from collections import Counter

tup_to_find_set = set(tup_to_find_test)
counts = Counter(self_per_list_test)

tup_dict_test = {k: v if k in tup_to_find_set else 0 for k, v in counts.items()}

print(tup_dict_test)

{('leaf', 'liquid'): 0, ('leaf', 'sweet'): 2, ('good', 'pea'): 3}
```

Comment: This is one line fashion of @BernardL solution right? It is very neat and smart! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Abbey, Yep, if you want to stick with `defaultdict`, it is indeed a one-liner. It's just advisable to use hashing via `set` to make it efficient.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't the default integer of `defaultdict(int)` zero?

Yes.

> Why I got 1 for the ('leaf', 'liquid') tuple?

You wrote:

```
tup_dict_test[tup_to_find_test]+=1
```

That is, find the current value—which creates a new one set to zero—then add one to it and store the result back.  The resulting value is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Without reinventing the wheel. You can use `counter` from the wonderful `collections` standard module library for this.

```
from collections import Counter

tup_to_find_test = [('good', 'pea'), ('leaf', 'sweet')] 
self_per_list_test = [('leaf', 'liquid'), ('leaf', 'sweet'), ('leaf', 'sweet'),('good', 'pea'),('good', 'pea'),('good', 'pea')]

c = Counter(self_per_list_test)

for key in c:
    if key not in tup_to_find_test:
        c[key] = 0

print(c)

>>Counter({('good', 'pea'): 3, ('leaf', 'sweet'): 2, ('leaf', 'liquid'): 0})
```

Here we create a counter based on `self_per_list_test` and updates the counts to zero if it is not found in `tup_to_find_test`. Hope this is a more intuitive method in solving your problem.

Comment: A quick question. Compared to `defaultdict`, is the `Counter` faster than using `defaultdict`?

Comment: Well, you cannot compare `defaultdict` to a `Counter`, `defaultdict` calls a factory function to supply missing values. A `Counter` is optimized to count hashable values. In this use case, if your purpose is just to count, I would go with `Counter`.

Comment: I tried both of them on my dataset. You are right. As my goal is to simply count the frequency of tuple, I should go for `Counter`. Thanks for your smart/straightforward solution! (I think I overthink about my question)

Comment: Yeah hoped it helped. If you found any of the answers here useful and alas, please accept the best answer here that helped you solved your problem.